# large chain of if statements will not work at all

Tags: visual-c++

many greetings stackoverflow, PLEASE help!
 i am using c++ in visual studio 2012 for the following source code. Please overlook the if statement overkill as i need this many for purposes not relevant right now. First i will show you the code, then explain what i want from it and what the code outputs instead.

the source code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream> 
#include <random>
#include <Windows.h>


using namespace std;



int main() {


 int q;  for (q=1;q<70;q++) {

int a=0; int b=0;    int n; n=10;

if (n==1)  {
    a+=32412936;a-=478; b+=32412936;b-=478;
            }  else if (n==2) {
    a+=82448439;a-  =479; b+=82448439;b-=479;
               }   
else if (n==3)  {
    a+=36433027;a-=480; b+=36433027;b-=480;
                 }else if (n==4)  {
    a+=41541519;a-=481; b+=41541519;b-=481;
                 }
else if (n=5) {a+=26414039;a-=482; b+=26414039;b-=482;
                 } else if (n==6) {a+=33448382;a-=483; b+=33448382;b-=483;
                 } 
else if (n==7)  {a+=11713443;a-=484; b+=11713443;b-=484;
                 }else if (n==8)  {a+=13250112;a-=485; b+=13250112;b-=485;
                 }
else if (n==9)  {a+=29504347;a-=486; b+=29504347;b-=486;
                 }else  if (n==10) {a+=31324116;a-=487; b+=31324116;b-=487;
                 }
else if (n==11) {a+=35122249;a-=488; b+=35122249;b-=488;
                 }else if (n==12) {a+=28172515;a-=489; b+=28172515;b-=489;
                 }  
else if (n==13) {a+=26236144;a-=490; b+=26236144;b-=490;
                 }else if (n==14) {a+=13493747;a-=491; b+=13493747;b-=491;
                 }
else if (n=15) {a+=11225344;a-=492; b+=11225344;b-=492;
                 }else if (n==16) {a+=30264815;a-=493; b+=30264815;b=-493;
                 }
else if (n==17) {a+=48382722;a-=494; b+=48382722;b-=494;
                }else if (n==18) {a+=71720355;a-=495; b+=71720355;b-=495;
                }
else if (n==19) {a+=18141943;a=-496; b+=18141943;b-=496;
                }else  if (n==20) {a+=11223520;a-=497; b+=11223520;b-=497;
                }
else if (n==21) {a+=14172839;a-=498; b+=14172839;b-=498;
                }else if (n==22) {a+=22724027;a-=499; b+=22724027;b-=499;
                }  
else if (n==23) {a+=40423831;a-=500; b+=40423831;b-=500;
                }else if (n==24) {a+=37124163;a-=501; b+=37124163;b-=501;
                }
else if (n=25)  {a+=18463525;a-=502; b+=18463525;b-=502;
                }else if (n==26) {a+=24243746;a-=503; b+=24243746;b-=503;
                }
else if (n==27) {a+=19231045;a-=504; b+=19231045;b-=504;
                }else if (n==28) {a+=18254164;a-=505; b+=18254164;b-=505;
                }
else if (n==29) {a+=14152123;a=-506; b+=14152123;b-=506;
                }else  if (n==30) {a+=35394362;a-=507; b+=35394362;b-=507;
                }
else if (n==31) {a+=34354224;a-=508; b+=34354224;b-=508;
                }  else if (n==32) {a+=20503446;a-=509; b+=20503446;b-=509;
                }  
else if (n==33) {a+=50211748;a-=510; b+=50211748;b-=510;
                }else if (n==34) {a+=45164213;a-=511; b+=45164213;b-=511;
                }
else if (n=35) {a+=19253344;a-=512; b+=19253344;b-=512;
                }else if (n==36) {a+=17538448;a-=513; b+=17538448;b-=513;
                }
else if (n==37) {a+=65193712;a-=514; b+=65193712;b-=514;
                }else if (n==38) {a+=12625441;a-=515; b+=12625441;b-=515;
                }
else if (n==39) {a+=31281648;a-=516; b+=31281648;b-=516;
                }else  if (n==40) {a+=18391744;a-=517; b+=18391744;b-=517;
                }
else if (n==41) {a+=15351330;a-=518; b+=15351330;b-=518;
                }  else if (n==42) {a+=15637224;a-=519; b+=15637224;b-=519;
                } 
else if (n==43) {a+=27104423;a-=520; b+=27104423;b-=520;
                }else if (n==44) {a+=38739446;a-=521; b+=38739446;b-=521;
                }
else if (n=45) {a+=41434431;a-=522; b+=41434431;b-=522;
               }else if (n==46) {a+=48252749;a-=523; b+=48252749;b-=523;
               }
else if (n==47) {a+=20263033;a-=524; b+=20263033;b-=524;
               }else if (n==48) {a+=16422136;a-=525; b+=16422136;b-=525;
               }
else if (n==49) {a+=19161821;a-=526; b+=19161821;b-=526;
               }else  if (n==50) {a+=23810252;a-=527; b+=23810252;b-=527;
               }
else if (n==51) {a+=35717436;a-=528; b+=35717436;b-=528;
               }else if (n==52) {a+=41104049;a-=529; b+=41104049;b-=529;
               }  
else if (n==53) {a+=16404437;a-=530; b+=16404437;b-=530;
               }else if (n==54) {a+=13538502;a-=531; b+=13538502;b-=531;
               }
else if (n=55) {a+=95638275;a-=532; b+=95638275;b-=532;
               }else if (n==56) {a+=23442524;a-=533; b+=23442524;b-=533;
               }
else if (n==57) {a+=61034411;a-=534; b+=61034411;b-=534;
                }else if (n==58) {a+=35252041;a-=535; b+=35252041;b-=535;
                }
else if (n==59) {a+=47281421;a-=536; b+=47281421;b-=536;
                }else  if (n==60) {a+=29112124;a-=537; b+=29112124;b-=537;
                }
else if (n==61) {a+=15194123;a-=538; b+=15194123;b-=538;
                }else if (n==62) {a+=42284530;a-=539; b+=42284530;b-=539;
                }  
else if (n==63) {a+=11204091;a-=540; b+=11204091;b-=540;
                }else if (n==64) {a+=49446102;a-=541; b+=49446102;b-=541;
                }       
else if (n=65) {a+=18234024;a-=542; b+=18234024;b-=542;
               }else if (n==66) {a+=29528441;a-=543; b+=29528441;b-=543;
               }
else if (n==67) {a+=10183142;a-=544; b+=10183142;b-=544;
               }else if (n==68) {a+=50491436;a-=545; b+=50491436;b-=545;
               }
else if (n==69) {a+=40291143;a-=546; b+=40291143;b-=546;
               }else  if (n==70) {a+=35144418;a-=547; b+=35144418;b-=547;
               }
else if (n==71) {a+=40534222;a-=548; b+=40534222;b-=548;
                }else if (n==72) {a+=14203223;a-=549; b+=14203223;b-=549;
                }  
else if (n==73) {a+=26492724;a-=550; b+=26492724;b-=550;
                 }else if (n==74) {a+=36492781;a-=551; b+=36492781;b-=551;
                 }
else if (n=75) {a+=41027224;a-=552; b+=41027224;b-=552;
               }else if (n==76) {a+=22264722;a-=553; b+=22264722;b-=553;       
               }
else if (n==77) {a+=37222944;a-=554; b+=37222944;b-=554;
                }else if (n==78) {a+=47422240;a-=555; b+=47422240;b-=555;
                }
else if (n==79) {a+=39262730;a-=556; b+=39262730;b-=556;
                }else  if (n==80) {a+=45104814;a-=557; b+=45104814;b-=557;
                }
else if (n==81) {a+=31037183;a-=558; b+=31037183;b-=558;
                }  else if (n==82) {a+=91636263;a-=559; b+=91636263;b-=559;
                }  
else if (n==83) {a+=37534382;a-=560; b+=37534382;b-=560;
                 }else if (n=84) {a=25645403-561; b=25645403-561;
                 }; 

cout <<"   "<<a;  n++;}

_getch();    return 0;    }
```

The loop at the top is supposed to ensure that the value n increases by 1 on each iteration.
Each if statement would be read by the computer and 'else' would ensure that if the value 'n 'is equal to the number on its left 'a' would consist of the final value assigned to it within the adjacent curly braces (first a number is added to a , then another is subtracted, after which the final value of a is obtained). In theory 70 DIFFERENT values, ALL within curly braces, of a would be printed on to the console/terminal, as 'n' changes value. Instead i get this:
    26413557   26413557   26413557   26413557   26413557   26413557   26413557
    26413557   26413557   26413557   26413557   26413557   26413557   26413557   264
    13557   26413557   26413557   26413557   26413557   26413557   26413557   264135
    57   26413557   26413557   26413557   26413557   26413557   26413557   26413557
    26413557   26413557   26413557   26413557   26413557   26413557   26413557   2
    6413557   26413557   26413557   26413557   26413557   26413557   26413557   2641
    3557   26413557   26413557   26413557   26413557   26413557   26413557   2641355
    7   26413557   26413557   26413557   26413557   26413557   26413557   26413557
    26413557   26413557   26413557   26413557   26413557   26413557   26413557   26
    413557   26413557   26413557   26413557

all the same numbers and this particular number does NOT result from any 'a' value within brackets.

Please reply...thanks!

Comment: else if (n=5) {a+=26414039;a-=482; b+=26414039;b-=482; } Check this sintax if it's correct, or you mispelled copying. Should be n==5.

Comment: Also, try to format your code better. What about using a switch statement?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Large chain of if statements wont work, c++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21264349/large-chain-of-if-statements-wont-work-c)

Answer (score 0):

From what you wrote, I think it's correct that you get always the same value: you're creating a, b and n variable each cycle. n is always set to 10 at the moment of checking. Please review your post.